# How can I parse Outsystems OSVSTATE token to subsequent requests in Jmeter?

Tags: javascript, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, outsystems

I have created a jmeter script for Outsystems applications ( by recording and as well as creating raw request) however when I try to pass _OSVSTATE value from login page to subsequent requests I am getting an base64 encoding errors. I tried sending the request with encoding and without encoding but the result is same. Could anyone please help me/ advise me of how to overcome this issue. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Please post your codes here. It will help others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into [View state in OutSystems Applications](https://www.outsystems.com/forums/discussion/10458/view-state-in-outsystems-applications/) article I don't think you need to encode/decode the `__OSVSTATE` parameter, you just need to extract it from the previous response, save into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) and add the variable as the parameter for the next request.

You can extract the value using i.e. [CSS Selector Extractor](http://newsite-dev.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-cssjquery-extractor-jmeter/) configured like:

- Name of created variable: anything meaningful, i.e. `OSVSTATE`
- CSS Selector Expression: `input[__id=__OSVSTATE]`
- Attribute: `value`

[image]

That's it, now you have the parameter value in the `${OSVSTATE}` JMeter Variable, feel free to use it where required.